# Configured provision throughput was exceeded?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a table with 100 write capacity and auto-scaling enabled. When inserting a small object each of around 160,000 units, it only goes up to around 15,000 and then it fails saying:

```
Error occuredProvisionedThroughputExceededException: 
The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded.
Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API.
```

What am I doing wrong? It should be working correctly as I have auto-scaling enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You either need to increase your write capacity or slow down the rate that you are writing to the table.

For capacity, you need to increase the upper bounds for write capacity. This is called "Maximum provisioned capacity" in the Auto Scaling section of the Dynamodb console.

Comment: I have already increased Maximum provisioned capacity to 4000.

Comment: By slowing down the rate you mean decreasing the minimum/maximum capacity? I tried those low settings too but it didn't work

Comment: No, I mean slow down how fast you are writing to Dynamodb (requests per second).